# include in php not working

Tags: php, phpseclib

```
 <?php
    include("/Crypt/RSA.php");
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
     $token=base64_decode("iKmHdK3ChRBPAU/I/wTKld4up91TMrcWjkE+VGggVryRzvhKC6l+sZ3F+j+qyW8rxg01/uu2E3z6aVirwmQ0ig==");
     $private=base64_decode("MIIBVQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT8wggE7AgEAAkEAyUFH4OJOUOKh38raMxiQhmtuNSMxcznSdt9fWiJZOYpnv1rbu3h/heNCIOxOHSrlMz8FAKAW6rd9ddXNcm4myQIDAQABAkEApGbPcMVtdGWuFkJ/PH40kZnwzTeSja4OX0zZd6fXe0hBZZjA1nREuLGh2x7OXkpArytgQ35W2NHCxeldniTmgQIhAO7SB0Mhb/HLst4ty6HT2kZoAC/N2UdsBtQFdC8sNNxXAiEA17t4cVsx5EYYFifDSUwawz5pJSfrQYk1C0H1atL9Id8CIQDOtJL8k7BkxD5o95JM2yUN02518eGiY+n1EVNikQyfuQIgdph88fQsTU2rWCKr3NOVstfQfbigP/rpyjKMdBlhRwkCIE/x13OF2JUHlA5DqxCVh3LHMDDowr7SkQ2QVkqfBcAb");
    $rsa->loadKey($privateKey);
    echo $rsa->decrypt($cipher);
?>
```

i kept my include_path as `.:/usr/local/lib/php`

i am getting errors like this:

> Warning: include(/Crypt/RSA.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/futureti/public_html/reg2.php on line 2
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/Crypt/RSA.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/futureti/public_html/reg2.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Crypt_RSA' not found in /home/futureti/public_html/reg2.php on line 3

Comment: Remove the leading slash from your include statement, you're currently defining an absolute path from the root of the drive.

Comment: Where did you install Crypt/RSA.php? Have you installed it?

Comment: yes i installed from PEAR packages in Cpanel the directory structure is root folder under it php, public_html and other some folders for website. when I installed in php it created a directory Crypt in it RSA.php exists. In public_html the php script i want to run exists. And one more thing when I installed Crypt_RSA it was installed but at last it prompted an error like in bin folder phpize can't be created.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
include('../Crypt/RSA.php');
```

Your current leading `/` is creating an absolute link, so going right back to your root directory.

`../` means one folder up.

Comment: Where is the file you're calling it, and where is the file you want? Whats the file structure?

Comment: in public_html i have the web page in php as i am using cpanel from web hosting

Comment: Are they in two separate files, both in `public_html`?

Comment: rsa.php is in php/crypt and my web page is in public_html

Comment: Is `php` before `public_html`?

Comment: in root folder php and public_html are sub folders

Comment: still the same error once see i kept my include_path variable as ".:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php"

Comment: In that case try `include('RSA.php');` @user3481084

Comment: This is very difficult without seeing your folder structure haha... :( @user3481084

Comment: I installed Crypt_RSA from PEAR packages in Cpanel for webhosting. The directory structure is root folder under it php, public_html and other some folders for website. when I installed in php it created a directory Crypt in it RSA.php exists. In public_html the php script i want to run exists. if you interested i will give my details to log-in to my web hosting me too waiting for solution thanks

Comment: Try `/../php/Crypt/RSA.php` or `Crypt/RSA.php` @user3481084

Answer (score 0):

Try using the document root variable:

```
$doc_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include($doc_root . "/Crypt/RSA.php");
```

Comment: Warning: include(/home/futureti/public_html/Crypt/RSA.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/futureti/public_html/reg2.php on line 3

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/futureti/public_html/Crypt/RSA.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/futureti/public_html/reg2.php on line 3

Comment: Please update your question and post your directory structure. Without knowing exactly where RSA.php resides, we have no chance of helping you.

Comment: I got that /home/futureti/php/Crypt/RSA.php, i edited that but i got new error like this:                                                                     Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Crypt_RSA_ErrorHandler in /home/futureti/php/Crypt/RSA/ErrorHandler.php on line 125

Comment: is there another alternative for decryption in php which is encrypted in android